# Testing a method that does not return any value(jasmine angular4)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working on a project where i'm using jasmine for testing.
I have a situation where a method does not return any value but it just sets the class property. I know how to use spy on a method that returns a value but not sure how to use it on a method that does not return any value.I searched online but couldn't find any proper resource.
And the method is as follows

```
updateDvStatus() {
    this._http.get(this.functionControlUrl).subscribe(() => {
    this._active = true;
    }, (error) => {
      this.errorStatusCode = error.status;
      this.errorPageService.setStatusCode(this.errorStatusCode);
    })
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How to test a method that does not return anything**

The following is an example of testing a method that doesn't return anything.

```
var serviceUnderTest = {
  method: function() {
    console.log('this function does not return anything');
  }
};

it('should be called once', function() {
  spyOn(serviceUnderTest, 'method');

  serviceUnderTest.method();

  expect(serviceUnderTest.method.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  expect(serviceUnderTest.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
});
```

**How to test a callback**

I suspect your real problem though is testing that the function you are passing into the `subscribe()` function does what you expect. If *that* is what you are really asking, then the following might be helpful (note that I wrote this off the top of my head, so there might be a typo).

```
var serviceUnderTest = {
  method: function() {
    this.someOtherMethod(function() { this.active = true; });
  },
  someOtherMethod: function(func) {
    func();
  }
}

it('should execute the callback, setting "active" to true', function() {
  spyOn(serviceUnderTest, 'someOtherMethod');

  serviceUnderTest.method();

  expect(serviceUnderTest.someOtherMethod.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  var args = serviceUnderTest.someOtherMethod.calls.argsFor(0);
  expect(args.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  var callback = args[0];
  expect(typeof callback).toBe('function');

  expect(serviceUnderTest.active).toBeUndefined();
  callback();
  expect(serviceUnderTest.active).toBe(true);
});
```

**Your Scenario**

Sorry for the older syntax, I'm writing this from my head, so I'd rather it work, than be cool looking, but have some typos. Also, I haven't used Observables, so there is likely a better way to test them than what I am about to show you, and it probably amounts to creating a new Observable, and spying on subscribe. Since this is off the top of my head, we will have to make do.

```
it('should subscribe with a function that sets _active to true', function() {
  // Arrange
  var observable = jasmine.createSpyObj('Observable', ['subscribe']);
  spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(observable);

  // Act... (execute your function under test)
  service.updateDvStatus();

  // Assert
  expect(http.get.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(service.functionControlUrl);
  expect(observable.subscribe.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  var args = observable.subscribe.calls.argsFor(0);
  expect(args.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  var callback = args[0];
  expect(typeof callback).toBe('function');

  service._active = false;
  callback();
  expect(service._active).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Struck with the similar problem.In the question, The function defined does not expect any args and it just sets the class property. Is there any way to test this scenario ? Can you provide an example if thats not too much to ask for.

Comment: Updated with my callback example, but applied more closely to your scenario.

Comment: @151291 - If you want to ask another question, and then ping me about it, I will take a look

Comment: please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49588124/2034750

Comment: Thanks for the great post, although expect(serviceUnderTest.method.calls.count()).toBe(1);  did not work for me. I just had to create a spy variable like: let testSpy = spyOn(serviceUnderTest, 'method'); and then I could use: expect(testSpy.calls.count())